# How do I access an iframe from CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, webkit, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a webpage with an iframe.  I'd like to access the contents of the iframe using [CasperJS](http://www.casperjs.org).  In particular, I need to click buttons and fill a form.  How can I do that?

The main webpage is
[main.html](http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html):

```
<html><body>
<a id='main-a' href="javascript:console.log('pressed main-a');">main-a</a>
<iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<a id='main-b' href="javascript:console.log('pressed main-b');">main-b</a>
</body></html>
```

The iframe is:

```
<html><body>
<a id='iframe-c' href="javascript:console.log('pressed iframe-c');">iframe-c</a>
</body></html>
```

My naïve approach:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start("http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html", function() {
    this.click('a#main-a');
    this.click('a#main-b');
    this.click('a#iframe-c');
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Doesn't work, of course, because the `a#iframe-c` selector isn't valid in the main frame:

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html"
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/iframe.html, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step 2/2 http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html (HTTP 200)
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: a#main-a
[info] [remote] pressed main-a
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: a#main-b
[info] [remote] pressed main-b
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: a#iframe-c
FAIL CasperError: Cannot dispatch click event on nonexistent selector: a#iframe-c
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "CasperError: Cannot dispatch click event on nonexistent selector: a#iframe-c"
CasperError: Cannot dispatch click event on nonexistent selector: a#iframe-c    
  /tmp:901 in mouseEvent
  /tmp:365 in click
  /tmp/test.js:9
  /tmp:1103 in runStep
  /tmp:324 in checkStep
```

Is there any way to make this work?  A hack that involves poking into phantomjs directly would be fine, but I don't know what to do there.

I'm using CasperJS version 1.0.0-RC1 and phantomjs version 1.6.0.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Spent forever looking for this, and of course I found the answer minutes after posting the question.

I can use the new frame switching commands added to phantomjs in [this commit](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/f386f7d484).  Specifically, the `this.page.switchToChildFrame(0)` and `this.page.switchToParentFrame()` functions.  It appears undocumented, and it also seems that the methods have been [changed](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=654) for upcoming releases, but it does work:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start("http://jim.sh/~jim/tmp/casper/main.html", function() {
    this.click('a#main-a');
    this.click('a#main-b');
    this.page.switchToChildFrame(0);
    this.click('a#iframe-c');
    this.page.switchToParentFrame();
});

casper.run(function() {
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Jim, did you happen to know if you can this.test.assertVisible('#someElemInsideIframe') after switching? Seems to barf for me but this.click(...) works.

Comment: I don't, sorry.  Visibility might be tested in some other way that doesn't work well with frames, I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you see @olleolleolle's answer? withFrame is a documented method.

Comment: Yes, I did.  `withFrame` did not exist when I asked this question or accepted this answer, but it sounds like the right thing to use from now on.

Answer (score 35):

From 1.0 you can use [withFrame](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe)

```
  casper.open("http://www.example.com/page.html", function() {
    casper.withFrame('flashHolder', function() {
      this.test.assertSelectorExists('#the-flash-thing', 'Should show Flash');
    });
  });
```

Comment: How could this work with frames that have dynamic names? I can't rely on the frame index (eg 0 or 1) instead because social services like twitter (via addthis) often load in their own iframes in the background.

Comment: you can use frame index instead of frame name - http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe

Answer (score 4):

As a matter of fact you'll have to use the new `--web-security=no`
feature provided by `Phantomjs 1.5` in order to be able to access those
`iFrames` and their contents.

Comment: Not really related -- this example is a same-domain iframe and cross-domain security isn't my problem.  See my own answer for what worked (`--web-security=no` is still not required there).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have different frames(frame1 and frame2) and we have to access different elements(like click or check if div tag exits or not) of those frames.

```
casper.withFrame('frame1', function() {
    var file = '//*[@id="profile_file"]';
    casper.thenClick(x(file));
});

casper.withFrame('frame2', function() {
  casper.then(function () {
     casper.waitForSelector('#pageDIV',
            function pass() {
                console.log("pass");
            },
            function fail(){
                console.log("fail");
            }
      );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
casper.start("url here...", function() { 
    this.withFrame(0, function() {
        this.evaluate(function() {
            document.querySelector('img#btn_start').click();
        })
    })
});
```

You can replace the zero with the name of the iframe.