# How to forcefully click on a button in an iframe using jQuery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

How to forcefully click on a button in an iframe using jQuery or PHP?

example

```
<iframe src="www.google.com"></iframe>
```

I want to press the button or anchor tag in that iframe.

And also change anchor tag target -> '_self'

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this for reasons of security.

Comment: its `src` not `scr` for a start!

Comment: Is the iframe on same origin with your first page (where iframe is loaded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on "not possible"...

The "[Same origin policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" apply: your only way of communicating with the contents of iframes that come from another [domain|subdomain|protocol|port] is through the [postMessage API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-document_messaging), which of course requires the other part (the document inside the iframe) to listen to your messages. This means that unless you're a google employee with access to the search frontend, this won't be possible.

If you work at google and want to press a button forcefully, I recommend standing with your foot on your mouse: your weight will help push it with more strength.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Blocked by Browsers for security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

On serverside you could use CasperJS to click some stuff inside an iFrame. See here 
[How do I access an iframe from CasperJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150194/how-do-i-access-an-iframe-from-casperjs)