# Selector path for YouTube comments returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, casperjs

Using [<kbd>CasperJS</kbd>](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/), I would like to retrieve how many comments are on a YouTube video.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://youtube.com/watch?v=I1HpEzxYHxE', function() {

    this.echo(this.getTitle()); // test to see if page loaded correctly

    var comments = this.evaluate(function() {   
        return document.querySelector('div.DJa').innerText;
    });

    this.echo(comments);
});

casper.run();
```

The output of that is:

```
Android Eclipse Tutorial #1 - Building an App From Scratch - YouTube
null
```

This is a screenshot of the source HTML of that YouTube video:

[image]

I'm looking to get the `innerText` of the selector `div.DJa`.

Here is a screenshot of the Properties list of that selector:

[image]

That list says that the `innerText` property holds the value `"ALL COMMENTS (49)"`, so that is my expected output, instead of `null`.

Can anyone explain *why* the output is `null` and/or how to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
casper.then(function(){
     onapp_name = this.evaluate(function() {
         return __utils__.findOne('#LXCType_name').getAttribute('value');
     });
});
```

And echo `onapp_name` variable...

[Documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/faq.html#what-s-this-mysterious-utils-object)

Comment: Yes, i spent 1 hour on this problem after answer. The code above doesn't work. But i think that problem is with iframe tag(your div inside this iframe).
see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150194/how-do-i-access-an-iframe-from-casperjs)

Comment: If you can use the link you suggested to create an answer that works, I'll give you +25. I don't have time to research this right now.