# Get html from iframe - "failed to read contentDocument" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I writing some scraping script on casperjs/phantomjs and trying to get html from one of goodle ads iframe tags and getting error

Code:

```
iframe_node = $('iframe').contents().find('iframe[name^="google_ads_frame"]')[0]
html = a.contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

Error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': 
Blocked a frame with origin "http://example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)
```

Comment: You can change the context to the iframe from CasperJS like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14154214/1816580) and get the content from `casper.getHTML()`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following variables for  web-security, ssl-errors, and ssl-protocol:

```
casperjs --web-security=false --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any <your_script>.js
```

You cannot access cross-origin frames without adjusting these variables due to security settings.  This should allow you to enter the frames and grab the necessary content.